# CollectionType add action for database flush

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine, symfony4

I've created `CollectionType` form, which can add unlimited amount of `TicketTime` entities into one `Ticket` entity. It is connected via database by a `OneToMany` relation.

What I am trying to do is to add one `Ticket` and multiple `TicketTime`s to the database at one time. For example, one `Ticket` and 3 `TicketTime`s.

I would like to know how to make this method, so I can take one `Ticket` & multiple `TicketTime`s and flush them to the database.

My Controller action:

```
    public function createTicket(Request $request)
    {
        if ($this->get('security.authorization_checker')->isGranted('IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY')) {
            if ($this->getUser()->getrole() == 3) {
                $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
                $ticket = new Ticket();
                $timeArray = new ArrayCollection();

                $form = $this->createForm(TicketType::class, $ticket);

                $form->handleRequest($request);

                if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
                    foreach ($timeArray as $time) {
                        $time->setTicket($ticket);
                        $em->persist($time);
                    }
                    $ticket->setTaken(0);

                    $em->persist($ticket);
                    $em->flush();

                    return $this->redirectToRoute('main');
                }
                return $this->render(
                    'create_ticket.html.twig',
                    array('form' => $form->createView())
                );
            }
        }
        return $this->redirectToRoute('main');
    }
```

Ticket entity:

```
/**
 * @Assert\NotBlank()
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="TicketTime", mappedBy="ticket", fetch="EXTRA_LAZY", orphanRemoval=true, cascade={"persist"})
 */
private $ticketTimes;
public function setTicketTimes($time): void
{
    $this->ticketTimes = $time;
}
/**
 * @return ArrayCollection|TicketTime[]
 */
public function getTicketTimes()
{
    return $this->ticketTimes;
}
```

TicketTime entity:

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Ticket", inversedBy="time")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
 */
private $ticket;

public function getTicket()
{
    return $this->ticket;
}

public function setTicket($ticket): void
{
    $this->ticket = $ticket;
}
```

Comment: 1. $timeArray doesn't seem to get populate anyhow, so it will be empty. 2. your post doesn't include a question. where exactly you want us to help you?

Comment: @iiirxs how do I populate it, so it gets values of CollectionType? I would like to know how to implement this add method so it takes one Ticket and multiple TicketTimes from one form

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to fix it by myself :)

What was wrong:
I needed to create add method in Ticket entity, so I will be able to add as many TicketTime's as I want, here's the code which I added into Ticket entity:

```
public function addTicketTime(TicketTime $time)
{
    $this->ticketTimes[] = $time;
    $time->setTicket($this);
    return $this;
}
```

I've also added some lines into Controller

```
........
if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
    $ticketTimes = $form->get('ticketTimes')->getData();

    foreach ($ticketTimes as $time) {
        $ticket->addTicketTime($time);
    }
.......
```